# Is this pseudocode correct for the following assignment?

Tags: computer-science, pseudocode, flowchart

The assignment:

*Draw a structured flowchart and write pseudocode that describes the process of guessing a number between 1 and 100. After each guess, the player is told that the guess is too high or too low. The process continues until the player guesses the correct number.*

My pseudocode:

```
Start
 Num1=6
 Get Num2
  while Num2 is not = to Num1
    if Num2 > Num1
      print "too high"
    else 
      print "too low"
    endif
    Get Num2
   endwhile
Stop
```

Comment: Why not trying to code something quickly (python/ruby) from this pseudo code to make sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you're writing pseudocode for the guessing game instead of the guesser. Your indentation levels are a bit funky, though. Don't forget to draw the flowchart, too.

Comment: @user3238583: Your `endwhile` doesn't match your `while`, and the second and third lines don't match the indentation of the fourth.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK. You might want to add an acknowledgement that they entered the correct number after the endwhile